# Is there a way to change loop through all sheets, identify a certain background color and change that background color from one hex code to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Dislike a color that is currently on the sheet and want to change them all to a different color without doing it cell by cell.

Answer (score 2):

**Change a background Color in all sheets**

Please check all file names, color assignments abd excluded sheet names before running the scripts

```
function changeColor() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const toClr = "#ffffff";//new color
  const fmClr = "#d9ead3";//old color
  const excl = ["Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"];//excluded sheets
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => !~excl.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    let bs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getMaxRows(), sh.getMaxColumns()).getBackgrounds().map((r, i) => {
      return r.map((c, j) => c == fmClr ? toClr : c);
    });
    sh.getRange(1, 1, bs.length, bs[0].length).setBackgrounds(bs);
  });
}
```

The following function gets and lists all colors on all sheets.  It's helpful to get a list of colors on all of the sheets

```
function getAllColors() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const colors = ss.getSheets().reduce((a,sh,i) => {
    let clrs = [... new Set(sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getMaxRows(),sh.getMaxColumns()).getBackgrounds().flat())].join('\n')
    a.push([sh.getName(),clrs]);
    return a;
  },[["Sheet","Colors"]]);
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,colors.length,colors[0].length).setValues(colors);
}
```

A function to get all sheet names. It's nice to have to create the excluded sheets list

```
function getAllSheetNames() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const names = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(names));
}
```

- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [new Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)
- [... Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)